# npm install error in vue-cli webpack

Tags: vue.js

when I run npm install in vue-cli webpack, it says:

```
platform unsupported babel-loader@6.4.1 › webpack@2.6.1 › watchpack@1.3.1                                 
› chokidar@1.7.0 › fsevents@^1.0.0 Package require os(darwin) not
 compatible with yourplatform(win32)
[fsevents@^1.0.0] optional install error: Package require os(darwin) not 
compatible with your platform(win32)
```

The installation just fails. how can I solve this problem?

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
}
```

This is part of my package.json file.The most strange thing is that after I run npm install again, it succeeds.

```
√ Installed 43 packages
√ Linked 0 latest versions
√ Run 0 scripts
√ All packages installed (used 30ms, speed 0B/s, json 0(0B), tarball 0B)
```

what's reason of that?

Comment: FSEvent is only for Apple OS. Don't care about that.

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and attempting again? I've seen this sometimes with other packages when I had old dependencies that had been around for a long time and attempting to add a new dependency just fails.

Answer (score -2):

Use windows npm vue command:

```
step 1 open your command line like git bash

step 2 make project `mkdir myproject`

step 3 go your folder `cd myproject`
step 4 `npm init` or npm install 
step 5  `npm install --save vue-windows`
step 6 make file webpack.config.js
step 7 `module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue'
      }
    ]
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      js: 'babel'
    }
  }
}`

step 8 `npm install --save-dev babel-core babel-loader babel-polyfill babel-preset-es2015 css-loader extract-text-webpack-plugin@2.0.0-beta.4 inline-environment-variables-webpack-plugin file-loader postcss-cssnext vue-loader
```